# How to tell what permissions are required for an Android Application in ADT?

Tags: android, adt

How can I tell what permissions an application will require without downloading it to an android phone and trying to install it?

I have the application files as a project that is building in ADT

Comment: You mean what permissions are declared or permissions that need to be declared?

Comment: Hmm maybe? Sorry.. new to Android dev.  So when I look at the Chrome App Info on an Android phone it shows me a PERMISSIONS section with a bunch of stuff listed.  How do I know what permissions the application that I'm writing will require?

Comment: you can look through this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html and anything that you know your using put it in there

Comment: So I have to manually specify what permissions my app needs?

Comment: @JuJoDi - indeed, you do.  There may be programs which attempt to guess based on static analysis of your code.